# df.loc column where name contains "x" and count rows where rows contains "y"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a pandas df and want to loc columns containing string "X" and then sum for every row where rows string contains "Y".

Desired results

| ABC | ABC | ABX | ABX | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | YA | A | 1 |
| A | A | YA | YA | 2 |

I've tried beginning below, ,but already here and error occurs.

> df['result'] = np.where(df.loc[:~df.columns.str.contains('X')]

**Error:**
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers

Anyone know how to go about?

Comment: none of the column has 'max' in them

Comment: @Naveed sorry. fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)+[`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)+[`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to count the values:

```
df['Result'] = (df.filter(like='X')
                  .stack()
                  .str.contains('Y')
                  .groupby(level=0).sum()
               )
```

Or with `apply`:

```
df['Result'] = (df.filter(like='X')
                  .apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('Y'))
                  .sum(axis=1)
               )
```

output:

```
  ABC ABC ABX ABX  Result
0   A   A  YA   A       1
1   A   A  YA  YA       2
```